# Is there a Pythagorean triple whose angles are 90, 45, and 45 degrees?

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

Is there a Pythagorean triple (a.k.a. an integer triangle) whose angles are 90, 45 and 45 degrees? I am trying to connect LEGO roads at angles other than the standard 90 degrees.

Comment: no, not integer lengths. Your triangle has lengths $(1,1,\sqrt 2)$

Comment: In answer to you question: No.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article [Hippasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippasus) is the story of the 5th century BCE discovery of the irrationality of square root of two and other irrationals.

Comment: No, but there are an infinite number that are close, eg (20, 21, 29) is a Pythagorean triple with the perpendicular legs almost equal, and the related (29, 29, 41) has an apex angle that's slightly less than 90°. You can find such relations from the continued fraction approximations to $\sqrt2$

Comment: @PM2Ring A slight expansion and that's a worthy answer. Legos click together with a tolerance, and once you're within that tolerance ...

Comment: It was a big blow to the world view of the Pythagoreans when they discovered that this very constructible number (the diagonal of a square) that thus, to them, clearly existed, wasn't in a whole number ratio to the sides.

Comment: If such a thing existed, since two of the sides would have the same length, would it really be a Pythagorean Triple, or just a Pythagorean Double?

Comment: I'll second what @Neil_UK said. Given OP's context of Lego, an answer about constructing arbitrarily-close cases would be useful and interesting.

Comment: For a more Lego-oriented solution, you can try the [Bricks Stack Exchange](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: For a conclusive proof that 3.5²*2=5² (i.e. $\sqrt{2}=\frac{10}{7}$) within Lego tolerance, look at [p.32](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/06000/6199/032.jpg) of the [instructions for set 6199](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/6199/Hydro_Crystallisation_Station_) (blue and trans-green pieces plus yellow topping - note Lego piece length is usually measured end-to-end, but has to be measured from center-of-first- to center-of-last-stud-or-connector here). Not sure it will help with something as flat as roads, though.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to try this myself. Good catch!

Comment: I asked at Bricks Stack Exchange too. https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/connecting-out-of-system-roads But the answer I got came from a totally different direction (no pun intended). I think the "close enough" integer triangle approach is easier to implement than the technic axle approach described there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot have an integer Pythagorean Triple whose angles are $45°, 45°$ and $90°$.

[image]

Assume on the triangle we have sides $a$. Then by Pythagoras' Theorem,

$$a^2+a^2=2a^2=(a\sqrt{2})^2$$

This means the hypotenuse is no longer an integer length, because now it measures $a\sqrt2$. This means no such Pythagoren Triple exists.

Comment: Is that `sqrt(2*a)` or `sqrt(2)*a`? It's hard to tell due to the font.

Comment: Sorry, it's $\sqrt{2} \times a$, or more conventionally, $a\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: And critically, sqrt(2) is irrational, and cannot be represented by a fraction.

Comment: For completeness, $a\sqrt 2$ could be rational - for example, if $a$ were $\sqrt 2$. Of course, in that case, the sides would be irrational. It would be more correct to say the "either the hypotenuse or the sides must be of irrational length"

Answer (score 15):

No, since if the perpendicular sides are $a$ in length, the hypotenuse would be $a\sqrt2$. But $\sqrt2$ is irrational, so $a\sqrt2$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 15):

In your context you might be interested in isosceles triangles that are almost right.  As others have said, a right isosceles triangle has sides that are $a,a,a\sqrt 2$ and as $\sqrt 2$ is not rational we cannot have an integer sided one.  However, if we find a rational number that is close to $\sqrt 2$ we can find isosceles triangles that are close to right.  We have $\sqrt 2 \approx 1.414213$, while $\frac 75 = 1.4$ is not so far away, so a $5,5,7$ triangle is close to right.  In fact the angle is $\arccos \left(\frac 1{50}\right)\approx 88.85^\circ$.  You might have enough give to tolerate that.  If not, given one triangle in the list is $a,a,b$ the next is $a+b,a+b,2a+b$, so the next is $12,12,17$, then $29,29,41$, and so on.  The get closer and closer to right as you progress.  If you are interested in where this comes from, you could look up [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Comment: Probably a typo: I guess it's `a + b, a + b, 2a + b` (`12=5+7,17=2*5+7`)?

Comment: @Christoph:  Thanks.  I had messed up an edit putting it in nicer form